# Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Guid

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

My page uses a GridView to show all clients to the user after he or she logs in. However I'm trying to get the GridView to show only those clients that belong to the respective user.

...the code behind:

```
String strConnString = ConfigurationManager
    .ConnectionStrings["BA_2013ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "getClients";
cmd.Parameters
    .Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier)
    .Value = txtUserId.Text.ToString();
cmd.Connection = con;

con.Open();

gvClients.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
gvClients.DataBind();

con.Close();
con.Dispose();
```

...the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.getClients
@UserId uniqueidentifier
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT ClientId, UserId, ClientName, EmailAddress, PhoneNumber, ServicesNum 
    FROM  Client_tb 
    WHERE UserId = @UserId  

END
```

when I run the page, I get the error: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Guid
...could I get some help with this please?

Comment: The error statement seems pretty clear. You need to convert your string to a Guid. Luckily, it has a [constructor for doing that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ff78dc(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to parse the string guid to `Guid` like:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = Guid.Parse(txtUserId.Text);
```

You can also pass the `string` value in a `Guid` constructor like:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = new Guid(txtUserId.Text);
```

Also there is no need to call `ToString` on TextBox's Text Field, it is already of type string.

*(Remember [Guid.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) is supported in .Net framework 4.0 and higher)*

If you are getting the input from a `TextBox` then chances are you might encounter invalid values for the `Guid` in that case you can use [`Guid.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) method.